# how to catch particular element of json format

Tags: jquery, json

json returns the value and I store in variable. For example

```
var person = {
    Name:"Shree",
    Address: "Ratopul",
    Profession: "Programmer",
    Address: [
        {
            District: "abc",
            Ward: "Tel",
            Tel:"235"
        },
        {
            District: "abc1",
            Ward: "Tel",
            Tel:"235"
        },
        {
            District: "abc2",
            Ward: "Tel",
            Tel: "235"
        }
    ]
};
```

I got a address through.

`var address=person.Address;`

But I want to catch a particular element of address.  How is it possible. I don't have any idea. Please help.

Comment: what does you this mean "i want to catch particular element of address"

Comment: I mean is it possible to search in `address` for `District` which `Tel` is `235`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var p1=     person.Address[0]  //first 
var p2=     person.Address[1]  //second
var p3=     person.Address[2]  //third

alert(p1.Ward);

**or**


    for (i=0; i< person.Address.length;i++)
    {
        var person=person.Address[i];
        if(person.Tel===235)
        {
           //this is the person i was looking for
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Address is just an array of objects.

```
var district = person.Address[0].District;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude is this what u r looking for?

```
var addresses=person.Address;
$.each(addresses,function(index,item){
alert(item.District+"-"+item.Ward);
if(item.Tel=="235")
{
  alert(item.District);
}
});
```